# Looking for a way to store and update nested and indexed mongoDB documents in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, mongodb, nested-loops

I'm trying to create a document in my collection that holds multiple users, which hold information about multiple projects and this for every day.

When I try to push the information to the collection. I can't get it to work to store the information in that order for multiple users on one day, or even update or push more information to that document.

I think the problem is the keys, but I might be using the php driver a bit wrong.

First I tried using the Jenssegers MongoDB driver for Laravel, but I think the options are a bit limited. Then I read the documentation for the Mongo PHP driver and things were working a bit better, but still no success.

```php
$users = User::all(); // fetching all users in our mysql db

foreach ($users as $index => $user) {
    // calling the toggl API to receive the information for each user
    $data = app('TogglServce')->ApiCall($user->toggl_token);

    // getting all the necessary information from the API
    $timeEntries = collect($data['data']['time_entries']);
    $res = [];
    $timeEntries->each(function ($e) use (&$res, $user) {

        $res[Carbon::parse($e['start'])->toDateString()][$user->id][$e['pid']][] = [
            'duration' => $e['duration'],
            'start' => $e['start'],
            'stop' => $e['stop'],
        ];
    });

    $collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->toggldata->toggldata; // MongoDB connection

    $entries = array_keys($res); // Getting each date from the api and putting them in an array

    // looping through each entry/date
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $projects = array_keys($res[$entry][$user->id]); // getting all the projects on that day from the api

        // looping through the projects to be added
        foreach ($projects as $project) {

            $obj[] = array('user_id' => $user->id);
            $lastIndex = count($obj) - 1;
            $obj[$lastIndex]['projects'][] = [
                'pid' => $project,
                'time_entries' => $res[$entry][$user->id][$project]
            ];

            $datematch = $collection->findOne(['date' => $entry, 'user' => $user->id]);
            // if there is no datematch, a document has to be created
            if (!$datematch) {
                $collection->insertOne(['date' => $entry, 'users' => $obj]);
            } else {
                // trying something different here, basically i wanted to update the existing entry, add the user on a new key (or if it already existed on the same) and add the new projects array
                $collection->updateOne(
                    ['date' => $entry],
                    [$set =>
                    [
                        "date" => $entry,
                        "users" => array(
                            'user_id' => $user->id,
                            'projects' => [
                                'time_durations' => $res[$entry][$user->id][$project]
                            ], ['upsert' => true]
                        )
                    ]]
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit excessive and I'm not sure if the nested array is the right way to store the information, when querying the data back it would be nice to query a day, see all users and which projects they did and what time they spent on it. But the function I'm trying to make here is to create that information in the first place, for each user.

The raw query doesn't seem the work either. The using the wildcard to find the key makes the query update each entry. Is there any trick to find the right user and push the update on that array?

```js
db.times.update(
    { 'users' : { $elemMatch : { 'projects' : { $elemMatch : { 'pid' : 153446871
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$push": {
        "users.$.projects.$.time_entries": {
            "duration": 544,
            "start": "2019-08-29T09:54:56+00:00"
        }
    }
},
{ multi: true
}
);
WriteResult({
    "nMatched": 1,
    "nUpserted": 0,
    "nModified": 1
})
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow, I dunno if this helps but there are numerous syntactic issues with your code